# Gradle Android task crashing with unclear error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to run a Gradle Android task generated by libGDX utility (the desktop task runs fine) in IntelliJ IDEA, but I'm only getting this nonspecific error message. What is the issue, or where are the logs, or how to enabled logs?

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:core:assemble, :android:assembleDebug]
Information:24. 10. 2015 16:58 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 9s 415ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':android:proguardDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

[image]

PS: Not sure if it is relevant, but I have modified build files and ProGuard file to support Scala as described [there](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-Scala).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way of getting any useful logs from IntelliJ IDEA. I solved the problem by running Gradle from console.

```
gradlew assemble --stacktrace --info
```

Problem was Gradle could not find `tools.jar`. Adding system environment variable `JAVA_HOME` pointing to Java SDK directory fixed the issue.